# Flutter preview icons showing broken asset image on code completion

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

When i first installed the flutter and dart extensions the icon preview was working alright, but when i developed in an environment where there was no wi-fi the icon preview broke. (Not sure that was the problem)

[image]

I've tried reinstalling all flutter and dart related extensions but the problem still persists.
I'd appreciate any suggestions

P.D.: Working on VsCode 1.58.0 and MacOs 11.4

Comment: https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/2896 did it resolve?

Comment: Nope, and wasn't the same issue, mine tries to show but seems like it can't find the resource

Comment: Same thing here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be a regression in VS Code:

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/128315
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/119786

Unfortunately I'm unable to find a workaround so will need to wait for a fix. I would recommend putting 's on those issues, as right now the open issue doesn't seem to be treated as a regression but rather fixing some technical debt.