# Icon data preview is broken in visual studio code-flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

[Image showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DmhF.png)

My flutter vesion is v3.24.0
My dart version is v3.24.2
My vs code version is 1.58.2

Comment: See [Flutter preview icons showing broken asset image on code completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68345670/flutter-preview-icons-showing-broken-asset-image-on-code-completion)

Comment: @DannyTuppeny thanks a lot!. i hope they fix it soon